# Linq to entities. NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I use VS 2008 and ado.net EF. I have two tables:

```
Shifts(SH_Id, WorkshopId,TabNum)
Workshops(WH_ID, WH_Name)
```

Shifts linked to Workshops(WorkshopId -- WH_ID) I'm trying to write query:

```
var data = _Context.Shifts.Where(w => w.TabNum == 1).First();
var workshop = data.Workshops.WH_ID;
```

It returns *NullReferenceException*. 
But following code returns WH_ID:

```
        var data2 = (from o in _Context.Shifts
                    where o.TabNum == 1
                    select new
                    {
                        wh_id = o.Workshops.WH_Id

                    });

        var workshop = data2.First().Workshops.wh_id;
```

Why data.Workshops.WH_ID returns NullReferenceException?

Comment: because data2 may have no items, so asking for the First() method will throw `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Your second approach returns some value as WH_Id or it just does not throws exception, and value is null?

Comment: If to use SQL Server query SELECT WorkshopId FROM SHIFTS WHERE TabNum =  1, wll be returned one record. Second aproach returns required value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the Entity framework is not returning the attached entities from the query.

The reason why this works for the second example is because the entire query is translated to SQL and run on the server.

To solve this try

```
var data = _Context.Shifts.Include("Workshops").Where(w => w.TabNum == 1).First();
```

or even

```
var data = _Context.Shifts.Include("Workshops").First(w => w.TabNum == 1);
```

Comment: What if lazy-loading is enabled, as it should be by default?

Comment: It works. I'm newbie in Entity framework. I suppose second example would work in Linq To SQL

Answer (score -2):

You are not sure if there are any items in the sequence, so check it firs:

```
var data2 = (from o in _Context.Shifts
             where o.TabNum == 1
             select new
             {
                wh_id = o.Workshops.WH_Id

             });

if(data2.Count() > 0)
{
    var workshop = data2.First().wh_id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, use `FirstOrDefault()` and check for a null.

Comment: I think OP is asking *Why data.Workshops.WH_ID returns NullReferenceException?* when second query works fine